# How to set Default Message when there is no data

Tags: azure-logic-apps

How to set default Message like 'No Data' when there is no rows present in SQL query using Azure Logic App.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to return to the caller?

Should be very simple.

1. Test for the number of rows returned and set a Variable.
2. Add a Switch Action with a Case for 0 rows, use the Default >0.
3. In the 0 Case, use a Compose Action to create the "No Data" message.  In the Default Case, do the regular logic.

Comment: Can u explain with example... I want to display to the user .

Comment: @Selvi.P Well, the steps I listed above are the example.  We're not inclined to do the work for you.  It's very simple so please try it and come back if you have any specific problems.

Comment: See, I understood the logic you mentioned above. I am not asking to apply the logic in query level. Asked if there is any built-in function for this like SSRS. Well I'm not paying for you.

Comment: @Selvi.P The Compose Action is the function you're looking for.  And you can pay with pointe. :)

Comment: I asked built-in function which means a single function can do the work without applying additional blocks or additional logics. Anyhow thx for the useless comments..Usually I don't pay for unnecessary works 

Comment: @Selvi.P So, I guess you haven't actually tried.  The Compose Action is a built in function and does exactly what you're asking about.  Good advice is only useless if you don't use it.